# Typed HTTP client in Azure function not registering properly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, httpclient, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to create a typed http client in an Azure function through DI, when I set it like below, it is not getting into the lambda and therefore is not setting the BaseAddress.

```
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>(client => {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        });
```

In the service that will create the methods for the client, it consumes like so:

```
  public Service(HttpClient client){
```

Then in other classes I'm injecting in Startup as:

```
  public AClass(Service service){
```

I'm following the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients), what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>(client => {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
});
```

will already add the service to the collection. I would suggest removing the singleton

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
```

Lastly, the service was registered with an abstraction, yet you try to inject the implementation.

```
public AClass(Service service){
```

I would suggest injecting the abstraction instead where needed

```
public AClass(IService service){ //<-- NOTE THE INTERFACE
```

Comment: Indeed the problem was solved by removing the manual singleton. Thanks!