# typed client setup in Startup.cs, cannot get info in injected service

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httpclient

I have a demo Azure function and setup the typed client as follow:
But I can't get base address in injected httpclient instance. Any advice? Thanks

```
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();//Comment out this line will make it work
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
            });

        }
```

```
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task LogMsg()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(httpClient.BaseAddress);
        }
```

Updates:
Remove the AddSignleton line will work...
See link in comment

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165401/typed-http-client-in-azure-function-not-registering-properly?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can't get the base address in injected **httpclient** instance

Try to remove the `AddSingleton<MyServicehttp>()` Registration in Configuration Portion.

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
       public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
       {
           builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
           builder.Services.AddScoped<Customlog>();
           //Removed AddSingleton in service registration
              //builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyServiceshttp>()    
              builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyServicehttp>(client =>
           {
               // this code never runs
               client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
           });
       }
   }
```

If you want to use the singleton, try to inject `HttpClientFactory` inside your Service instance like (**MyServiceshttp**).

Refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5617#issuecomment-586177259)